# Marking up a block of preformatted text with tabs and newlines

Tags: pug

I’d like to put this block of code into Jade (the indent is a tab):

```
function isSafe(number) {
    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?$/i.test(number);
}

typeof number === 'string' && isSafe(number) && typeof eval(number) !== 'number'
```

When I do it like this, the blank line disappears:

```
pre
    code
        | function isSafe(number) {
        |    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?$/i.test(number);
        | }

        | typeof number === 'string' &amp;&amp; isSafe(number) &amp;&amp; typeof eval(number) !== 'number'
```

When I do it like this, the pipe shows up:

```
pre
    code
        | function isSafe(number) {
        |    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?$/i.test(number);
        | }
        |
        | typeof number === 'string' &amp;&amp; isSafe(number) &amp;&amp; typeof eval(number) !== 'number'
```

And when I do it like this, the tab turns into a space:

```
pre
    code.
        function isSafe(number) {
            return /^\d+(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?$/i.test(number);
        }

        typeof number === 'string' &amp;&amp; isSafe(number) &amp;&amp; typeof eval(number) !== 'number'
```

What’s the right way to mark that up?

Comment: Would it be possible to improve this question by extending it to the case of demonstrating HTML tags in block code with line breaks? That is, converting `pre <h1> hi </h1>...` into `<pre>&lt;h1&gt; hi &lt;/h1&gt;...</pre>`, except with more elements and line breaks in there (can't do this in a SO comment). I thought of asking a new question on SO but this question is too similar to mine so I thought they might be merged. If this request is too confusing, I could post an "Answer" to clarify, if you'd like.

Comment: @chharvey: That doesn’t sound like the same question at all; you’ll be fine asking a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there needs to be a space after the pipe:

```
pre
    code
        | function isSafe(number) {
        |    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?$/i.test(number);
        | }
        |·← here
        | typeof number === 'string' &amp;&amp; isSafe(number) &amp;&amp; typeof eval(number) !== 'number'
```